# Table borders are missing

Tags: tables, border

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\newsavebox{\toptabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

\sbox{\toptabular}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} l r @{\hspace{3em}} l r @{} }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\bfseries Probit Regression Results} \\
  \midrule
  Dep.\@ Variable &             Excess return sign   &   No.\@ Observations &       \num{254} \\
  Model           &           Probit   &   Df Residuals       &       \num{248} \\
  Methods         &              MLE   &   Df Model           &         \num{5} \\
  Date            & Thu, 16 Apr 2020   &   Pseudo R-squ.      &    \num{0.1311} \\
  Time            &         00:35:44   &   Log-Likelihood     &   \num{-149.65} \\
  Converge        &             True   &   LL-Null            &   \num{-172.23} \\
  Covariance Type &        nonrobust   &   LLR p-value        & \num{1.341e-08} \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}
\usebox{\toptabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular*}{\wd\toptabular}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=-2.4]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=-2.3,table-align-text-pre=false,table-space-text-pre={[}]
  S[table-format=-1.3,table-space-text-post={]}]% the minus also covers the second digit
  @{}
}
\toprule
       &   {Correlation Coefficient} & {Standard Error} &  {$z$} & {$P>|z|$} &  [0.025 &  0.975] \\
\midrule
const  &  -5.1870 &     1.270 & -4.083 &     0.000 &  -7.677 & -2.697  \\
Recession    &  -0.8608 &     0.394 & -2.183 &     0.029 &  -1.634 & -0.088  \\
Dividend to price &   0.3881 &     0.087 &  4.483 &     0.000 &   0.218 &  0.558  \\
Earning to price     &  11.3808 &     2.526 &  4.505 &     0.000 &   6.429 & 16.332  \\
Term spread    &  -1.3759 &     1.721 & -0.799 &     0.424 &  -4.750 &  1.998  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code above for drawing but I draw another table and the results was that in the picture, but that happened when I used the package `xltabular` to draw a description table, how i can fix that.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding some instructions to make your code minimally compilable. Please feel free to add further explanations and comments.

Comment: Off-topic: 3 of the 5 estimates you call "correlation coefficients" exceed 1 in absolute value. Is this really true? Are the estimates maybe regression coefficients rather than correlation coefficients?

Comment: Yes, that's right I will adjust that, but i recompiled the code and it's still giving the same results.

Comment: the table on bottom is wider-- but you are using width of the top table which is smaller

Answer (score 1):

Some of the table headers in the second table are quite long; taken as a whole, the second table is just too wide to fit in the width of the first table.

I suggest you (a) shorten quite a few of the header cells and (b) use `tabular*` environments for both table, setting both widths to `\textwidth`. I would also reduce the number of digits shown for the regression coefficients (*not* correlation coefficients!) from 4 to 3. Finally, I'd left-align the contents of all four columns in the first table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tight-spacing]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX determine optimal intercolumn whitespace 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
   ll @{\hspace{3em}} ll }
\toprule
  \multicolumn{4}{l}{\bfseries Probit Regression Results} \\
  \midrule
  Dep.\ Variable  & Excess return sign &   No.\ Observations  &       \num{254} \\
  Model           &           Probit   &   Df Residuals       &       \num{248} \\
  Method          &              MLE   &   Df Model           &         \num{5} \\
  Date            & Thu, 16 Apr 2020   &   Pseudo R$^{2}$     &    \num{0.1311} \\
  Time            &         00:35:44   &   Log-Likelihood     &   \num{-149.65} \\
  Converge        &             True   &   LL-Null            &   \num{-172.23} \\
  Covariance Type &        nonrobust   &   LLR $p$-value      & \num{1.341e-08} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=-1.3,round-mode=places,round-precision=3]
  S[table-format= 1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format= 1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  @{}
}
\toprule
   & {Coeff.} & {Std.\ Error} & {$z$} & {$P>|z|$} & {[0.025} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.975]} \\
\midrule
const             &  -5.1870 &     1.270 & -4.083 &     0.000 &  -7.677 & -2.697  \\
Recession         &  -0.8608 &     0.394 & -2.183 &     0.029 &  -1.634 & -0.088  \\
Dividend to price &   0.3881 &     0.087 &  4.483 &     0.000 &   0.218 &  0.558  \\
Earning to price  &  11.3808 &     2.526 &  4.505 &     0.000 &   6.429 & 16.332  \\
Term spread       &  -1.3759 &     1.721 & -0.799 &     0.424 &  -4.750 &  1.998  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it does not work, I think the problem is with the class document. But everything seems fine, however, after I added the package xltabular tables starting to look like this.

Comment: @NizarHijazeen - Please clarify what you mean by "it does not work". E,g., if you use a document class other than `article`, you really need to say so explicitly in the body of your posting. I don't see how loading (or not loading) the `xltabular` package should affect the look of the tables generated by the code shown above.

Comment: Please accept my apology, I forgot to put the document class, \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno]{memoir}

Comment: @NizarHijazeen - Changing `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno]{memoir}` does not fundamentally affect the "look" of either table.

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same as @Mico answer (1) ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newsavebox{\toptabular}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering

\sbox{\toptabular}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} l r @{\hspace{3em}} l r @{} }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\bfseries Probit Regression Results} \\
  \midrule
  Dep.\@ Variable &             Excess return sign   &   No.\@ Observations &       \num{254} \\
  Model           &           Probit   &   Df Residuals       &       \num{248} \\
  Methods         &              MLE   &   Df Model           &         \num{5} \\
  Date            & Thu, 16 Apr 2020   &   Pseudo R-squ.      &    \num{0.1311} \\
  Time            &         00:35:44   &   Log-Likelihood     &   \num{-149.65} \\
  Converge        &             True   &   LL-Null            &   \num{-172.23} \\
  Covariance Type &        nonrobust   &   LLR p-value        & \num{1.341e-08} \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
}
\usebox{\toptabular}

\bigskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}   % <--- new
\begin{tabular*}{\wd\toptabular}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=-2.4]
  S[table-format= 1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  S[table-format= 1.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3,table-align-text-pre=false,table-space-text-pre={[}]
  S[table-format= 2.3,table-space-text-post={]}]% the minus also covers the second digit
  @{}
}
\toprule
       &   {\makecell{Correlation\\ Coefficient}}   % <--- changed
            &   {\makecell{Standard\\ Error}}       % <--- changed
                &  {$z$} & {$P>|z|$} &  [0.025 &  0.975] \\
\midrule
const  &  -5.1870 &     1.270 & -4.083 &     0.000 &  -7.677 & -2.697  \\
Recession    &  -0.8608 &     0.394 & -2.183 &     0.029 &  -1.634 & -0.088  \\
Dividend to price &   0.3881 &     0.087 &  4.483 &     0.000 &   0.218 &  0.558  \\
Earning to price     &  11.3808 &     2.526 &  4.505 &     0.000 &   6.429 & 16.332  \\
Term spread    &  -1.3759 &     1.721 & -0.799 &     0.424 &  -4.750 &  1.998  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In comparison to your MWE I added before your second table `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` and write column headers of the second and third column in two lines by use of the `makecell` command from the package of the same name.  With this the second table width is shrink to the width of `\toptabular`.

Comment: @Mico, thank you! I will make this change asap (I only focused to LaTeX aspect of table ;-).